# How to change keyboard shortcut settings from the terminal

Tags: applications

I am looking to create a script that automatically sets up Elementary exactly how I want it. I have not yet figured out how to set the keyboard shortcuts via the command line, specifically the short cuts to open the browser and open email.
Thanks!
Luke

Comment: I have found using gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys home '<Super>f' appears to work however doesn't actually launch the application

Answer (score 0):

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys home "'f'"

Was the correct command